# Transformation of two gamma variables

Tags: density-function, gamma-distribution

If you have **$\frac{X}{X+Y}$** where **X** and **Y** are both independent Gamma distributions where **$\alpha$** for both **X** and **Y** is different, but **$\beta$** is the same for both, then how would that be different from the pdf for **$\frac{X}{X+Y}$** where alpha is the same but beta is different?

The first scenario is given at the top of this pdf http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/PDFs/GammaBeta.pdf

Comment: Is this the solution? http://math.stackexchange.com/a/190695

Comment: Yes, it is! .....